# Почему при объединении двух объектов в один они автоматически сортируются?

Tags: javascript

Я пытаюсь объединить два объекта в один, но элементы автоматически сортируются. (сначала выводятся свойства, у которых ключи - это Цифры, потом идут свойства, у которых ключи - это буквы). Мне нужно наоборот.

Мне нужен новый объект , где сначала будут идти свойства , у которых ключи - Буквы, а потом уже свойства, у которых ключи - Цифры.

Я пробовал объединять через Object.assign(), spread оператор, но все равно сначала выводяться свойства, у которых ключ - это цифра.

[image]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно это исправить?

```js
let letterObj = {
  A: [{ name: "one" }, { name: "two" }],
  B: [{ name: "one" }, { name: "two" }],
};

let numberObj = {
  1: [{ name: "one" }, { name: "two" }],
  2: [{ name: "one" }, { name: "two" }],
};

let concatObj = { ...letterObj, ...numberObj };

console.log(concatObj);
```

Comment: У объектов в принципе нет никакой определённой сортировки, поэтому вопрос не имеет смысла

Comment: А почему тогда сначала выводятся свойства, у которых ключ - цифра. Хотя сначала через spread добавляю объект с буквами.

Comment: А впрочем, [спецификация](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys) предписывает помнить порядок добавления для строковых ключей, но не для числовых

Comment: У объектов не предусмотрено определенность добавления. Поэтому программе все равно вы через spread что добавляете. Она начинает итеративно добавлять ключи, со значениями. А вот ключ в виде цифры встает впереди, потому что создатели JS хотели, чтобы он стоял впереди.

Comment: Если хотите, чтобы запомнился порядок, используйте массив. Не думаю, что задача такая, что его нельзя реализовать через массивы.

Comment: @eccs0103 *ключ в виде цифры встает впереди, потому что создатели JS хотели, чтобы он стоял впереди.* Думаю, что всё проще - это следствие оптимизации выбора значения свойства по заданному ключу. Для оптимизации поиска ключи во внутреннем представлении сортируются, причём используется binary collation. И числовые значения оказываются "впередее".

Comment: @Akina ну так создатели все-таки хотели же)) Ради оптимизации или ешё чего-то, но они хотели этого))

Comment: вывод `console.log` в принципе не специфицирован - каждый браузер может реализовывать так, как ему удобно, при этом правила обхода свойств описаны в спецификации

Comment: Всем спасибо. По итогу: я изменил объект на массив и уже далее работал с массивом. Сделал сортировку и решил задачу.

Answer (score 1):

**Исходный вариант** - числа идут первыми с сортировкой, остальные ключи в порядке добавления:

```js
let letterObj = {
  A: "one",
  Z: "one",
  B: "one",
};

let numberObj = {
  3: "one",
  1: "one",
  2: "one",
};

let concatObj = { ...letterObj, ...numberObj };

console.log("Исходный вариант", concatObj);
```

---

*Для экспериментов создадим пару функций: одна создаёт новый объект, вторая выводит новый объект в консоль.*

---

**Делаем имена ключей строками**

```js
/* Создаём новый объект */
function fObjectsOrderedAssign(...args) {
  const newObj = {};
  args.forEach(arg => {
    Object.entries(arg).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      newObj[key] = value;
    });
  });
  return newObj;
}
/* Перебираем объект и выводим в консоль*/
function fObjectsEnum(obj) {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(key, value);
  });
}

let letterObj = {
  "A": "one",
  "Z": "one",
  "B": "one",
};

let numberObj = {
  "3": "one",
  "1": "one",
  "2": "one",
};

let n = fObjectsOrderedAssign(letterObj, numberObj);
console.log("Вариант с ключами-строками", n);
fObjectsEnum(n);
```

Результат тот же, эффекта по-прежнему не наблюдаем :-(

---

**Делаем имена ключей строками с добавлением префикса**

```js
/* Создаём новый объект */
function fObjectsOrderedAssign(...args) {
  const newObj = {};
  args.forEach(arg => {
    Object.entries(arg).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      newObj[`_${key}`] = value;
    });
  });
  return newObj;
}
/* Перебираем объект и выводим в консоль*/
function fObjectsEnum(obj) {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(key, value);
  });
}

let letterObj = {
  A: "one",
  Z: "one",
  B: "one",
};

let numberObj = {
  3: "one",
  1: "one",
  2: "one",
};

let n = fObjectsOrderedAssign(letterObj, numberObj);
console.log("Вариант с ключами-строками и префиксами", n);
fObjectsEnum(n);
```

Ага. Теперь буквы там, где нужно, но числовые ключи всё ещё сортируются...

---

**Делаем имена ключей строками с префиксами в исходных объектах**

```js
/* Создаём новый объект */
function fObjectsOrderedAssign(...args) {
  const newObj = {};
  args.forEach(arg => {
    Object.entries(arg).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      newObj[key] = value;
    });
  });
  return newObj;
}
/* Перебираем объект и выводим в консоль*/
function fObjectsEnum(obj) {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(key, value);
  });
}

let letterObj = {
  "_A": "one",
  "_Z": "one",
  "_B": "one",
};

let numberObj = {
  "_3": "one",
  "_1": "one",
  "_2": "one",
};

let n = fObjectsOrderedAssign(letterObj, numberObj);
console.log("Вариант с ключами-строками и префиксами в исходных объектах", n);
fObjectsEnum(n);
```

Вот! Теперь всё правильно :-)

---

**Итог**

Необходимо явно задавать ключам строковый тип. Кроме того, во избежание приведения типов, добавлять префикс, и делать поправку на него. Тогда будет работать и для исходного варианта:

```js
let letterObj = {
  "_A": "one",
  "_Z": "one",
  "_B": "one",
};

let numberObj = {
  "_3": "one",
  "_1": "one",
  "_2": "one",
};

let concatObj = { ...letterObj, ...numberObj };

console.log("Исходный вариант", concatObj);
```

Comment: попробуй отрицательные числа - с ними тоже должно сработать :) либо числа не удовлетворяющие +0 ≤ i < 2^32 - 1.